# Is $f(x) = x^2$ a function of $Z \rightarrow Z^{+}$?

Tags: functions

For some function $f: Z \rightarrow Z^{+}$

Is $f(x) = x^2$ a function that maps all integers to all positive integers?

According to my textbook, it is, but
I am unsure because for $x=0$, $f(0) = 0$ which is not in the target $Z^{+}$. So does that mean it is not a function of $f: Z \rightarrow Z^{+}$?

**Textbook:**

> Find a function whose domain is the set of all integers and whose
>   target is the set of all positive integers that satisfies each set of
>   properties.
>
> (a) Neither one-to-one, nor onto.
>
> Solution: $f(n) = n^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: Please also read the discussion in the comments. It depends on the country and on the general understanding in the textbook.]

You are absolutely right. We could fix it with $f(n) = n^2+1$.

You *can* sometimes encounter "positive" meaning "non-negative". But that should be clearly stated in the context. Similarly, some authors take $\mathbb N$ to be $\mathbb Z_{\ge0}$. This may be a case of that consensus, but then it should be like that throughout the textbook at least.

Comment: Acrually, this depends on what you denote $\mathbf Z^+$. If it is the same as $\mathbf N$, it is OK.

Comment: @Bernard I agree, but writing "positive integers" in words would be a bit misleading, don't you think?

Comment: Here we would say `strictly positive’ to make the difference, and their set would be denoted $\mathbf Z^{*+}$.

Comment: I suppose it just depends on the context. I personally prefer non-negative. If I just read “the positive [something]s” without context, then I’m going to assume $0$ is excluded.

Comment: Perhaps due to the influence of Bourbaki, in France $0$ is generally considered to be "positive".

Comment: I thought there might be cultural differences. Are you French, Bernard? I am Danish, and here "positive" and "greater than" are strict by default (we may add "strictly" for emphasis), and we say "weakly positive" and "weakly greater than" for the non-strict cases.